# Install FreeDOS over Netboot

Tags: partitioning, installation, freedos, netboot

So, I'm trying to install FreeDOS onto an old PC. I have no Floppy Disk or Blank CDs. I'm booting into USB from PLoP on MBR, but this has proven fruitless in my endeavor, as it only allows me to access FDISK and repartition, but doesn't allow me to change active partition. So, I was wondering if FreeDos could be installed over a network boot, and if so, how?

Comment: I’m not sure I completely get it. You currently boot FreeDOS from a USB drive. You use Plop to boot from USB. Plop is installed in the HDD’s MBR?

Comment: @DanielB Correct! I'm trying to use FreeDos'  Install ISO to fully install it to the HDD as a main OS. I'm going to be using the unit as a Dos gaming machine (Not  using DOSBox, I want the full experience). After using FDISK to change active partition, it makes me reboot, making the USB drive the active partition again.

Comment: The USB drive can’t be “the active partition”. That’s of course because there’s no “the”. Every disk can have one. The BIOS decides which disk is used.

Comment: ...! Wow. I can't believe I was under that impression. Well, Freedos says "Freedos can be installed to the followig destinaion  drive: Current Fixed disk drive 1" and then it shows my USB stick as C:, for some reason. It also calls the disk I want to use D: in FDisk, which may have something to do with it, but I'm not sure. @DanielB